# If I delete a document does it still need a recycle?

Tags: javascript, xpages

In Javascript I'm iterating through an array of UNIDs and getting a NotesDocument by UNID, then I do a doc.remove(true);

having done that is it necessary to do a doc.recycle()?

Comment: If you are not getting an error when calling recycle then I would say yes, you do need to since there is still an object in memory. If you get get an error, then no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is **yes**.

For newbies, Notes objects in Java consist of a Java object and a reference to a C++ object. So when you a Java object becomes null (or useless), garbage collector will clear the memory space after a certain amount of time. However, the C++ handle will persist. So we are recycling notes objects to destroy C++ object references. [This](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21097861) page has a good explanation abouyt recycling.

On the other hand, `doc.remove()` can be thought as a state change. Moreover, if *soft deletion* is enabled in your database, it won't even remove the document, will just *mark as deleted* (you have to call `.removePermanently()` to hard-delete it). The C++ object reference will stay in the memory.

Therefore, remove method will not trigger a recycle for the object. Recycle is only triggerred by the object itself or its parent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should still recycle it.  It's an object at that point not a document.